# The http used in the function is undefined. Why?

Tags: angular, http, typescript

- My Component Source

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';

  //import { DatatableComponent } from '../../shared/ui/datatable/datatable.component'

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<button id="testBtn"></button>'
  })


  export class MarketComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( public http: Http ) { } 

    ngOnInit() {

      let btn = document.getElementById("testBtn");
        if(btn){
          btn.addEventListener('click',

            function(){

              this.http.get('./test.json')
              .map(response=>response.json())
              .subscribe(
                data => { //success
                  console.log("success");
                },
                error => console.log("HttpRequestButton Error"), //error
                () => console.log("CategoryCount HttpRequestButton Get Test Finish")
              );

            }
          );
        } // if end

      }
    }
  ```

I wonder...

I added the Click event to the addEventListener method.

The http used in the function is undefined. Why?
I do not know the reason.

I have to use http inside the function.
Is there a way?

Comment: use an arrow function instead, and have a read on **this** in javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: addEventListener is jQuery event so the http function is undefined inside the JQuery block. For button click event just do like this <button (click)="functionName()">Click</button>

Comment: By the way, should not you return response.json()?

Comment: I would also just use (click)="handler()" in template.. No need for JQuery like element lookup. Then put http inside handler.. Your method would also warrant an ngDestroy to removeEventListener otherwise you'd likely run into memory leaks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code

```
 btn.addEventListener('click',
          function(){
            this.http.get('./test.json')
```

Should be

```
 btn.addEventListener('click',
          () => {
            this.http.get('./test.json')
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

This 'this' is not the 'this' you want. You can use arrow function instead or call bind(this) in the end.

```
 function(){

        this.http.get('./test.json')
        .map(response=>response.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => { //success
            console.log("success");
          },
          error => console.log("HttpRequestButton Error"), //error
          () => console.log("CategoryCount HttpRequestButton Get Test 
         Finish")
        );

      }.bind(this)
```

In fact, you should implement that like :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<button (click)="onClick()"></button>'
})


export class MarketComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( public http: Http ) { } 

    ngOnInit() {}

    onClick(){
       this.http.get('./test.json')
        .map(response=>response.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => { //success
            console.log("success");
          },
          error => console.log("HttpRequestButton Error"), //error
          () => console.log("CategoryCount HttpRequestButton Get Test 
           Finish")
        );

    }

}
```